# Raspberry Pi - Open rdesktop connec

Tags: raspbian, raspberry-pi4

I'm as the title says, i'm trying to open an rdesktop connection on boot but cannot get it to work.

I placed a .desktop file in .config\autostart that should open a shell file. The file then runs this command.

```
rdesktop -f -u *Username* *Password *Domain* *Server*
```

When run directly the command works.

The .desktop file -

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec="/home/rdesktop.sh"
Name=stac0.desktop
#END1
#chmod +x ~/.config/autostart/stac0.desktop
#tee -a  ~/.config/autostart/stac0.desktop << END1
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
```

I then validated it using the following command

```
desktop-file-validate ~/.config/autostart/stac0.desktop
```

The .sh file being executed

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 30s
rdesktop -f -u gcorruga -p Huhtamak1 -d EUR gbbla-antila
sleep 5s
rdesktop -f -u gcorruga -p Huhtamak1 -d EUR gbbla-antila
```

(The command is run twice because it often fails the first time the command is run, not sure why this is the case)

Any ideas on a better method or what I'm doing wrong?

-Tom

Answer (score 0):

I found this method that worked …

**Create a shell file**

We first need to create a shell file:

```
sudo nano rdesktop0.sh
```

Then add your rdesktop command to the file. Save the file and close it.

Next, we need to make the file executable, enter this into the console:

```
sudo chmod +x hello-world.sh
```

Now we have a functioning shell script to run the command. I'd recommend testing it by running the following command:

```
sh rdesktop0.sh
```

**Executing the file on startup**

Use nano to create/edit a file here:

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/autostart/myapp.desktop
```

Then add the following lines:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=sh rdesktop *variables*
```

---

Sources: [Create a Shell script](https://www.circuitbasics.com/how-to-write-and-run-a-shell-script-on-the-raspberry-pi/); [Run a command on start-up](https://www.tomshardware.com/uk/how-to/run-script-at-boot-raspberry-pi).